# Jquery select from a collection of jquery objects which is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I haven't been able to find this answer. I don't know if I'm searching wrong or my lexicon is incorrect but I am trying to get the selected elements of a group of jquery radio buttons. Here is my JS code:

```
var hideFieldsBasedOnRadioButtonValue = function () {
   var $employmentStatusRadioButtons = $(".edit-profile-employment-information input[name='user[profile_attributes][employment_status]']");

   var displayOrHideRequiredFields = function ($radioButton) {
     if ($radioButton.val() === "Full Time" || $radioButton.val() === "Part Time") {
       $radioButton.closest("div.form-row").next(".required-input-when-yes").removeClass("d-none");
     } else {
       $radioButton.closest("div.form-row").next(".required-input-when-yes").addClass("d-none");
     }
   }

   displayOrHideRequiredFields($(".edit-profile-employment-information input[name='user[profile_attributes][employment_status]']:checked"));

   $employmentStatusRadioButtons.on("change", function () {
     displayOrHideRequiredFields($(this));
   });
}
```

This is a stripped down version of this function. I have a few more radio buttons that need to either hide or display additional fields depending on the radio button's value. What I'm having trouble with specifically is I want to trim this line down:

```
 displayOrHideRequiredFields($(".edit-profile-employment-information input[name='user[profile_attributes][employment_status]']:checked"));
```

the $employmentStatusRadioButtons are a collection of jquery objects and I'm unable to figure out how to grab the selected one. Any help would be amazing.

Instead of using the same ".edit-profile-employment-information input[name='user[profile_attributes][employment_status]']" selector on this line and on line 2 of the code I want to do something like

```
displayOrHideRequiredFields($employmentStatusRadioButtons:checked);
```

Now that won't work. The closest I've been able to get this to work is by doing the following;

```
displayOrHideRequiredFields($employmentStatusRadioButtons.selector + ":checked")
```

But I don't really like how that looks. We aren't using ES6 or else it would be awesome.

I haven't been able to find anything to help me in this regard. Does anyone know any methods specifically where I can do something like this?

Comment: you can do `$employmentStatusRadioButtons.filter(':checked');`

Comment: @MarkBaijens I love you. That worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the jquery [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) function for filtering a variable with jQuery objects.

```js
var $radios = $('[name=test],[name=test2]');
var $radiosFiltered = $radios.filter(':checked');
$radiosFiltered.each(function(){
  console.log($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="test" value="1" checked>
<input type="radio" name="test" value="2">
<input type="radio" name="test" value="3">
<input type="radio" name="test2" value="4">
<input type="radio" name="test2" value="5" checked>
<input type="radio" name="test2" value="6">
```

Answer (score 1):

You was so close, you need to use filter to get the checked elements from your collection :

```
$employmentStatusRadioButtons.filter(':checked');
```

Comment: Thanks, man! I you were so close as well but Mark beat you to the punch so I had to accept his. Thanks though!!